# emacs issue with fontconfig-config_2.13.1

Tags: apt, emacs

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1.  I recently installed the emacs snap.  When I run emacs, I get many Fontconfig errors and warnings.  I looked for a solution and found a suggestion to regress to  fontconfig-config-2.12.6. (20.04.1 has 2.13.1) This works (i.e. the errors go away) but "apt update" wants to return me to 2.13.1.

1. Is there any way to get the emacs snap to use 2.13.1?

Comment: Is this what you need? [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)?

Comment: Since I posted the note, I've found out how to prevent updating a particular package.  I'll edit the entry.  Thanks.